# How to get everything except brackets from string using php preg_split?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-split

```
$str = "[10:42-23:10]part1[11:30-13:20]part2"
```

I wish to split it into something like:

```
[1] 10:42-23:10
[2] part1
[3] 11:30-13:20
[4] part2
```

The best I managed to come up with is:

```
$parts = preg_split("/(\\[*\\])\w+/", $str );
```

But this returns

```
[0] => [10:42-23:10
[1] => [11:30-13:20
[2] =>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also you can use regex in [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead of [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$str = "[10:42-23:10]part1[11:30-13:20]part2";
preg_match_all("/[^\[\]]+/", $str, $parts);
print_r($parts[0]);
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/rH87M)

Answer (score 3):

Split on alternative between `[` and `]`, and use the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to not catch empty parts.

```
$str = "[10:42-23:10]part1[11:30-13:20]part2";
$parts = preg_split("/\[|\]/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
print_r($parts);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10:42-23:10
    [1] => part1
    [2] => 11:30-13:20
    [3] => part2
)
```

**NB.**

Thank to @WiktorStribiżew , his regex `/[][]/` is much more efficient, I've some benchmark, it is about 40% faster.

```
$str = "[10:42-23:10]part1[11:30-13:20]part2";
$parts = preg_split("/[][]/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
print_r($parts);
```

Here is the perl script I have used to do the benchmark:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $str = "[10:42-23:10]part1[11:30-13:20]part2";

my $count = -5;
cmpthese($count, {
    '[][]' => sub {
        my @parts = split(/[][]/, $str);
    },
    '\[|\]' => sub {
        my @parts = split(/\[|\]/, $str);
    },
});
```

**Result:** (2 runs)

```
>perl -w benchmark.pl
          Rate \[|\]  [][]
\[|\] 536640/s    --  -40%
[][]  891396/s   66%    --
>Exit code: 0

>perl -w benchmark.pl
          Rate \[|\]  [][]
\[|\] 530867/s    --  -40%
[][]  885242/s   67%    --
>Exit code: 0
```

Comment: While the pattern is simple, you may write it even better, as `"/[][]/"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:True, but my regex appears to me more readable. It's only a point of vue

Comment: Sure, it is always a matter of taste/style. I prefer precision and performance to readability.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Mea culpa, I've just some benchmark between the two regex, yours is much more efficient, something about 40% !!! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Toto: I'm curious to see how you bench that!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I've done in perl with `Benchmark` package.

Comment: @Toto: with PHP results are similar, the alternation is sometimes a little faster with the example string (a string where the delimiters are relatively frequent), with a string with long parts without delimiters the character class is a little faster. Whatever the case the differences are ridiculous, so in practise...

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Sure, in practice it doesn't make difference, it's only 1 or 2 µs per match.

Comment: Note that it's also possible with pcre to use the STUDY modifier `~]|\[~S` that may improve this kind of pattern (the result of this modifier is sometime random, depending if informations to improve the search are found or not, but alternations starting with literal characters give good results in general).

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple regex to match any `[...]` substring ([`\[[^][]*]`](https://regex101.com/r/R8y7rS/1)) and wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group - then you can use it with [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag to get both the captures and the substrings in between matches:

```
$re = '/(\[[^][]*])/';
$str = '[10:42-23:10]part1[11:30-13:20]part2';
$matches = preg_split($re, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/g44mqa)

With this approach, you may have a better control of what you match inside square brackets, as you may adjust the pattern to only match time ranges, e.g.

```
(\[\d{2}:\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}])
```

A `[10:42-23:10]part1[11:30-13:20]part2[4][5]` will get split into `[10:42-23:10]`, `part1`, `[11:30-13:20]` and `part2[4][5]` (note the `[4][5]` are not split out).

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R8y7rS/2)

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, you can use `strtok`:

```
$result = [];
$tok = strtok($str, '[]');
do {
    if (!empty($tok))
        $result[] = $tok;
} while (false !== $tok = strtok('[]'));
```